# Swift: Downcast to known type

Tags: swift, option-type

I was just wondering…

```
let movie = item as? Movie
```

In this example `item` is either of type `Movie` or something else. In case of the latter `movie` will be assigned a nil value. Thus `movie` will be of type `Movie?`.

Now check out the next example:

```
let movie: Movie?

movie = item as? Movie
```

Let's say `movie` is a class variable which I'm assigning some value inside one of my class methods.

To me it feels like `as? Movie` is somewhat redundant, since `movie` is already known to be of type `Movie?`.

**Is there any kind of syntax in Swift that says: "Downcast this object to the same type as the object to which I'm assigning it to. Assign nil if this is an optional type and the downcast fails."?**

I was hoping for something like:

```
movie = item as?
```

or

```
movie =? movie
```

Comment: do you mean optional chaining?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: This would be a nice syntax shortcut.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existing answers correctly state that there is no built in functionality for this. But just to build on what's already been written here, it is possible to define an infix operator `=?` which implements the behavior you described in your question. For example:

```
infix operator =? {
    associativity none
    precedence 130
}

func =? <T>(inout lhs: T?, rhs: Any?) {
    lhs = rhs as? T
}

var movie: Movie?
let item: Any? = Movie(name: "some movie")

movie =? item
movie?.name // "some movie"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. I'll definitely use this in my next project.

Comment: Note that, infix `inout` operator cannot assign to `let` constant.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

See the type casting section of the swift documentation below:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-XID_514

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any kind of syntax in Swift ...

NO.

You have to implement by yourself

```
func conditionalCast<T, U>(val: T?) -> U? {
    return val as? U
}

// Usage:

class Movie {}
class Image {}    
let item:AnyObject = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? Movie() : Image()

let movie: Movie?
movie = conditionalCast(item)
```

You can make it as a custom unary operator ( postfix `/?` for exmaple):

```
postfix operator /? {}
postfix func /?<T, U>(val: T?) -> U? {
    return val as? U
}

let movie: Movie?
movie = item/?
```